# "Error Tidying. Could not tidy ... out of the way, by adding .BAD" when using Q2.deployElement()?

Tags: jpos

I am attempting to create 10_channel.xml and 20_mux.xml Beans dynamically, while Q2 is running already.

The user will provide info via JSON post request like below:

```json
    "config": {
        "keyset": "KEYSET_1",
        "pinblockFmt": "01 - ISO 0 Format",
        "acq": {
            "format": "VISANET",
            "portNumber": 9405
        },
        "iss": {
            "format": "ISO4",
            "portNumber": 9488
        }
    }
```

The code will take the above info, and use JDOM2 to create the xml files and place them in Q2 deploy folder

```java
    private void createJposChannel(Map<String, Object> client, String portName) {
        String isoChannel;
        String ip;

        if (client.get("format").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("VISANET")) {
            isoChannel = "org.jpos.iso.channel.VAPChannel";
        } else {
            isoChannel = "org.jpos.iso.channel.CSChannel";
        }

        if (client.containsKey("ip")) {
            ip = (String) client.get("ip");
        } else {
            ip = "10.x.x.x";
        }


        try {
            Element channelAdaptor = new Element("channel-adaptor");
            channelAdaptor.setAttribute("name", portName + "-channel");
            channelAdaptor.setAttribute("class", "org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor");
            channelAdaptor.setAttribute("logger", "Q2");

            Element channel = new Element("channel");
            channel.setAttribute("class", isoChannel);
            channel.setAttribute("packager", "org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager");
            channel.setAttribute("logger", "Q2");

            Element property0 = new Element("property");
            property0.setAttribute("name", "packager-config");
            property0.setAttribute("value", "src/main/resources/" +
                    client.get("format").toString().toLowerCase() + ".xml");

            Element property1 = new Element("property");
            property1.setAttribute("name", "host");
            property1.setAttribute("value", ip);

            Element property2 = new Element("property");
            property2.setAttribute("name", "port");
            property2.setAttribute("value", portName.split("-")[0]); //remove system #

            Element property3 = new Element("property");
            property3.setAttribute("name", "timeout");
            property3.setAttribute("value", "3600000"); //default timeout time

            channel.addContent(property0);
            channel.addContent(property1);
            channel.addContent(property2);
            channel.addContent(property3);

            Element in = new Element("in");
            in.setText(portName + "-channel-send");

            Element out = new Element("out");
            out.setText(portName + "-channel-receive");

            Element reconnect = new Element("reconnect-delay");
            reconnect.setText("10000");

            channelAdaptor.addContent(channel);
            channelAdaptor.addContent(in);
            channelAdaptor.addContent(out);
            channelAdaptor.addContent(reconnect);

            IsotesttoolApplication.q2.deployElement(channelAdaptor, String.format("10_%s_channel.xml", portName), false, true);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            /*XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
            xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xmlOutput.output(channelAdaptor, System.out);*/

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

There is very similar code creating the mux files as well. Will omit to keep post shorter.

However, I am getting the below error only for the acq channel, 10_9405-01_channel.xml. The muxes, and even the channel for port 9488, do not get any errors:

```xml
        <log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:52.198">
  <info>
    created deploy/10_9405-01_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:52.203">
  <warn>
    Error Tidying. Could not tidy  C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\10_9405-01_channel.xml out of the way, by adding .BAD
    It could not be called: C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\10_9405-01_channel.xml.BAD see log above for detail of problem.
  </warn>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:52.203" lifespan="3ms">
  <info>
    <exception name="Error on line 1 of document file:/C:/Users/username/ISOTOPE/src/main/java/deploy/10_9405-01_channel.xml: Premature end of file.">
    org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1 of document file:/C:/Users/username/ISOTOPE/src/main/java/deploy/10_9405-01_channel.xml: Premature end of file.
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:230)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:277)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:264)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1104)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:563)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:392)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.run(Q2.java:258)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/username/ISOTOPE/src/main/java/deploy/10_9405-01_channel.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1467)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1042)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:867)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:796)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:142)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:644)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
    ... 7 more
    </exception>
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:52.204">
  <info>
    modified deploy/10_9405-01_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:52.211" lifespan="6ms">
  <info>
    deploy: C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\10_9405-01_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="channel/10.x.x.x:9405" at="2023-10-20T12:09:52.328" lifespan="81ms">
  <connect>
    Try 0 10.x.x.x:9405
      Connection established to 10.x.x.x:9405
  </connect>
</log>
<channel-adaptor name="9405-01-channel" class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
  <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.VAPChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="packager-config" value="src/main/resources/visanet.xml" />
    <property name="host" value="10.x.x.x" />
    <property name="port" value="9405" />
    <property name="timeout" value="3600000" />
  </channel>
  <in>9405-01-channel-send</in>
  <out>9405-01-channel-receive</out>
  <reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor><log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:54.220">
  <info>
    created deploy/20_9405-01_mux.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:54.238" lifespan="16ms">
  <info>
    deploy: C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\20_9405-01_mux.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:54.238">
  <info>
    modified deploy/20_9405-01_mux.xml
  </info>
</log>
<mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="9405-01-mux" realm="9405-01-realm">
  <in>9405-01-channel-receive</in>
  <out>9405-01-channel-send</out>
  <ready>9405-01-channel.ready</ready>
  <request-listener class="com.visa.ip.isotesttool.service.EchoResponder" />
  <request-listener class="com.visa.ip.isotesttool.service.AutoResponder" />
</mux><log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:56.239">
  <info>
    created deploy/10_9488-01_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:56.242" lifespan="3ms">
  <info>
    deploy: C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\10_9488-01_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:56.257">
  <info>
    modified deploy/10_9488-01_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="channel/10.x.x.x:9488" at="2023-10-20T12:09:56.343" lifespan="86ms">
  <connect>
    Try 0 10.x.x.x:9488
      Connection established to 10.x.x.x:9488
  </connect>
</log>
<channel-adaptor name="9488-01-channel" class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
  <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.CSChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="packager-config" value="src/main/resources/iso4.xml" />
    <property name="host" value="10.x.x.x" />
    <property name="port" value="9488" />
    <property name="timeout" value="3600000" />
  </channel>
  <in>9488-01-channel-send</in>
  <out>9488-01-channel-receive</out>
  <reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor><log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:58.245">
  <info>
    created deploy/20_9488-01_mux.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:58.251" lifespan="3ms">
  <info>
    deploy: C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\20_9488-01_mux.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2023-10-20T12:09:58.252">
  <info>
    modified deploy/20_9488-01_mux.xml
  </info>
</log>
```

Also, as you can see from the logs, it looks like the `10_9405-01_channel` and mux are both deploying anyways, after the error. My program is able to run fine despite that error, and I can see the transaction flow like I expect to.

So why is it complaining about "Error Tidying" and why is it only for one channel xml, and not the other?

Edit: Here is the generated deploy file that is failing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel-adaptor name="9405-01-channel" class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2" instance="208ac0a3-2b7e-4282-aab4-301d4f0859c3">
  <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.VAPChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="packager-config" value="src/main/resources/visanet.xml" />
    <property name="host" value="10.x.x.x" />
    <property name="port" value="9405" />
    <property name="timeout" value="3600000" />
  </channel>
  <in>9405-01-channel-send</in>
  <out>9405-01-channel-receive</out>
  <reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor>
```

versus the same code generated for the issuer port, which is not failing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel-adaptor name="9488-01-channel" class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2" instance="208ac0a3-2b7e-4282-aab4-301d4f0859c3">
  <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.CSChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="packager-config" value="src/main/resources/iso4.xml" />
    <property name="host" value="10.x.x.x" />
    <property name="port" value="9488" />
    <property name="timeout" value="3600000" />
  </channel>
  <in>9488-01-channel-send</in>
  <out>9488-01-channel-receive</out>
  <reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor>
```

Comment: I tried to deploy your failed file, and it didn't complain about premature end of file, I also see now that it is saying that for the first line. So I think it's most probable the reason is the one I mentioned in my answer.

Did you try to deploy that file after the fact? By manually moving it to `C:\Users\username\ISOTOPE\src\main\java\deploy\10_9405-01_channel.xml` after the failure?

Comment: Can you share the jPOS version you are using? Your stack trace doesn't match my line numbers. Or better yet, can you try with the last stable one (2.1.8)? or the latest snapshot of 2.1.9? And update the stacktrace?

Comment: Another question, does exactly the same happen every single time? Maybe you are generating in a success of events that make the second file get created just after the first one was read, but the second did not write anything. If that's the case, you may solve this by waiting some millis between the generatio of one file and the next one. So it is read in the next polling.

Comment: I was using JPOS 2.1.6, updating to 2.1.8 has the same issue. If I manually move the files generated to deploy folder, I do not see any issues. And yes, it happens the same every time , and only with the very first 10_channel.xml created. I increased the time between generated files by 10 seconds, but still same issue

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example? Something that just involves a main starting Q2 and then giving those errors? So I could reproduce and play with that and help you better (although it may be something that only happens in windows, in which case I won't be able to help, but someone else might). Also, if I can reproduce I could propose a PR to the main project to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you try to implement your own version of the `deploy` method as suggested in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, work was busy today with some other stuff. I will provide a small example for you to reproduce as soon as I can. And I have not made my own version of deploy yet, I'm hoping to do that on monday

Comment: I tried to edit the post with a simple reproducible program, but my company is blocking it for some reason, even though I masked any sensitive info. The program just consisted of a main method with the createJposChannel method, and it was able to reproduce the issue

Comment: I will try to write my own version of deploy and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging for the message:

> ```
> file:/C:/Users/username/ISOTOPE/src/main/java/deploy/10_9405-01_channel.xml: > Premature end of file.
> ```

And the fact that it works for other channels, I would say it's most probably due to `Q2` starting to read the file before it is completely written.

You should write the files to another temp folder and then perform a move operation, so that, when Q2 sees the file, it is already completely written.

Even if you didn't have this problem, that is a good practice, because if it doesn't happen frequently, it could happen sometime. That code would be in the `IsotesttoolApplication.q2.deployElement(` method.

**EDIT:** I see the `deployElement` method is from the `Q2` class, perhaps that method you do what I said, in that case, you could create an issue in the [jPOS's GitHub](https://github.com/jPOS/jPOS/issues).

Meanwhile, a workaround would be to write your version of the method that writes to another place and then perform the move.

**EDIT 2:** If the error consistently happens in the same way. It may be because `Q2` starts reading the second file, just after it was created. The error is consistent with having an empty XML file in the `deploy` directory:

```
touch deploy/test.xml
```

Will produce this:

```
    <exception name="Error on line 1 of document file:/media/disk/Documents/cabal-uy/migracion/jpos-externo/build/install/facade-externo/deploy/test.xml: Premature end of file.">
    org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1 of document file:/media/disk/Documents/cabal-uy/migracion/jpos-externo/build/install/facade-externo/deploy/test.xml: Premature end of file.
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:230)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:277)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:264)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1104)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:563)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:392)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.run(Q2.java:258)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Which is the same as yours.

So, I would try to add some time between the calls to `Q2.deploy`. Or, on the contrary, if you are processing them in different places, you could also check if creating the elements first, and then deploy them all at once could also work, but there is no warranty.

The best approach would be to try to fix that in jPOS, but for that you should provide a minimal reproducible example and create the issue.

Comment: I am currently deploying it by using Q2.deployElement(channelAdaptor, String.format("10_%s_channel.xml", portName), false, true);

So should I instead create the file using a different method and then move it?

Comment: I was just updating the answer when you wrote this comment, that's the EDIT, yes that's what you could do for now. This is a probable cause, if you add the generated deploy file to the question, we could check if the cause is another one.

Comment: Also, after the error, can you check if there are two versions of the file? One with the ,BAD extension and another one with just the xml?

Comment: I edited the post to include the generated deploy files.
Also, I do not see any files with .BAD extension; I only see the expected xml files there

Comment: That means that the `10_9405-01_channel.xml` is there?

Comment: @tytyty, I've just added more details to the answer.

Comment: @tytyty I just created [an issue for this](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/issues/564) in the jpos github repository, that could give you an idea of how to implement your version of `deployElement` while it is fixed. Also note that even if it is fixed, you would need to use the snapshot version or somehow patch the 2.1.8 version. Which you could do now following my directions, and then write a PR to the project to fix the issue. Becoming a code contributor in the process.

Comment: Issue is resolved by writing the files to a temporary location and then moving them to the deploy folder. I will keep this as my solution until a fix is in